# How to let my subfile use my definition in main file?

Tags: python, function, program-entry-point

I have this sentence in my `main.py` file:

```py
import pandas as pd

from modules.my_self_defined import *

input='1.csv'
df=just_an_example(input)
```

in ./modules/my_self_defined.py:

```py
def just_an_example(csv_file):
    a=pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    return a
```

Then when I run the file, it says pd is not defined in ./modules/my_self_defined.py

How could I make it work?

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking. Do you know what the `import ...` or `from ... import ...` statements do?

Comment: @Yevhen Kuzmovych Sorry I didn't say it clearly, I modified my question, please see if you have any suggestion.

Comment: Try import **pandas as pd** in my_self_defined.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use pandas (pd) in `my_self_defined.py`, not in `main.py`. So import it in `my_self_defined.py` instead and it'll work.

Comment: Thank you, I could make it work using this way. But wouldn't be bad if I use pandas(pd) both in main file and sub file?

Comment: If you import pandas in `main.py` it would work, it just would be not used -> redundant.